# How to add same flag to multiple commands in Oclif framework?

Tags: command-line-interface, flags, oclif

I'm writing a CLI using Heroku's CLI framework oclif. It works great, but I have a flag that is applicable to only list type commands. How to add the same flag to multiple commands but not to all in oclif?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have already found the answer but here is mine. You can set the value of multiple to true. This allows the flags to be declared multiple times. By default the value of multiple is false. Here is the link

https://oclif.io/docs/flags